# Why RandomSample fails and how to fix this?

Tags: bugs, random, sampling

Consider the following sampling:

```
weights = 10^RandomReal[{-13, Log10[35]}, 499500];
vals = Range[Length[weights]];
randomvals = RandomSample[weights -> vals];
```

Because of some reason, RandomSample returns

> Removed["$$Failure"]

The formal reason is a very wide range of weights. It is interesting that `RandomChoice[weights->vals]` works

How can this problem be fixed?

Comment: Looks like a bug. If you normalize the weights by total, then zero out those weights less than 10^-10 like this:  `Chop[Normalize[10^RandomReal[{-13, Log10[35]}, 499500], Total]];` then it works.

Comment: @flinty : but then I will lose particular elements of `vals` in the sampled version (this would be similar to what `RandomChoice` does). I would then need to look for missing elements and add them by hand.

Comment: Does it actually matter though? The probability of getting those elements is exceedingly small. The maximum weight is on the order of 3x10^14 times more likely than the minimum one. Also what you're doing doesn't make any sense - I was assuming you wanted to draw a subset sample, but you're actually just permuting the whole thing. `RandomSample[weights->vals]` does nothing but `RandomSample[vals]` which permutes the data. The weights add nothing here unless you're drawing a smaller sample.

Comment: @flinty : for my applied task (Monte-Carlo simulation of colliding particles, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/805520/about-simple-thermalization-simulation-why-the-final-distribution-is-not-e2), it does not seem to matter. For formal purposes (say, sorting `vals` in the descending order of `weights`), it also probably does not matter, as I would then use `SortBy[Transpose[weights,vals],-#[[1]]&][[All,2]]`. So this is just a curiosity question.

Comment: Code works for me with no problems, `"14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)"`.

Comment: @Goofy : maybe it is a version problem (I have 13.2@Windows 11).

Comment: Your syntax is wrong: `RandomSample[{Subscript[w, 1],Subscript[w, 2],\[Ellipsis]}->{Subscript[e, 1],Subscript[e, 2],\[Ellipsis]},n] ` The third argument is missing. Version MMA 13.4

Comment: I wonder if you are suffering from loss of precision.  If internally the weights are cumulatively summed (a plausible algorithm, I think) then loss of precision may cause consecutive sums to be the same (breaking some internal assumption).  You could try applying `SetPrecision[#,30]&` to the weights.